# CSS custom the trapezoid with inverted border radius

Tags: html, css

I want to customize this shape with CSS & HTML. It's the same trapezoid with some inverted border radius. How I can customize it?
This is image like this.

[image: Image here]

What I want is that it will be able to resize with the text in it. (Maybe it's called display inline... I'm not sure.) For example: I have short text and it should be 100px, with the long text it should be 400px.

```css
.dxTitle {
  /* I use Image instead of Custom transformed shape */
  background: url('https://image.ibb.co/eF0oRy/title_1.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-position: left 0px;
  height: 34px;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  /* Seem not important */
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dxTitle">
  <span style="font-weight:500">
    The Headers with short text
  </span>
</div>
<div class="dxTitle">
  <span style="font-weight:500">
    The Headers with long long long long text
  </span>
</div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: What you tried so far?

Comment: @Hanif I'm styling a accordion, I want to use this style for header of the accordion. Firstly, I used image instead of customing it by css but I wanted to control a width of trapezoid and prevented image to transform.

Comment: Ok fine then share your code for this area with us.

Comment: @Hanif [This is jsfiddle which I created](http://jsfiddle.net/645kcg8s/4/). So, what I want the trapezoid is auto resize with the text on headers of the accordion.

Comment: @HungVuong I've edited your question to include the linked JSFiddle. In the future, please include your attempts in the question for others to review/debug, and be sure that your question/code does not rely on external resources (like JSFiddle).

Comment: Can you please explain exactly what you want the trapezoid to look like/do? how exactly do you want to customize it? Maybe you could even include an image example of what you want it to look like.

Comment: @Tyler Roper My apologize for newbie. I'll be careful next post. Thanks you!

Comment: @Keara What Do you see the blue trapezoid in my code? What I want that it can **resize with the text** in it. (Maybe it's called _display inline_...I'm not sure)
**For example**: I have short text and it should be 100px, with the long text it should be 400px. Thanks you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```css
div {
  border-top: solid 1px #06f;
  margin: 1rem;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: .2em 0 0 .2em;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 0 -1em;
  padding: 0 1em 0 2em;
  line-height: 1.4;
  border-radius: 0 0 .2em 0;
  background: #06f;
  transform: skewX(-25deg);
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: 500;
}

span:before,
span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: .4em;
  height: .4em;
  background: #06f;
  right: -1.57em;
  border-radius: 0 0 .2em 0;
}

span:after {
  width: .5em;
  height: .5em;
  transform: skewX(-25deg);
  border-radius: .2em 0 0;
  background: #fff;
  right: -1.7em
}

span {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  transform: skewX(25deg);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1><span>Header</span></h1>
</div>
<div>
  <h1><span>Header with a short text</span></h1>
</div>
<div>
  <h1><span>Header with a long long long text</span></h1>
</div>
```

Comment: What a amazing custom style with CSS & HTML! Your skill is perfect. That's I need. Thanks you very much. (I learned much from your reply)

Comment: @HungVuong, happy to help!